# can´t connect to Tor while using school computer

Tags: configuration

OS of the Server is Windows Server 2012 R2 on Igel Computers with their own OS (think its Linux)

```
09.01.2018 12:25:31.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.01.2018 12:25:31.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.01.2018 12:25:31.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.01.2018 12:25:31.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.01.2018 12:25:31.700 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\bleichluca2310\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
09.01.2018 12:25:32.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
09.01.2018 12:29:42.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host F2044413DAC2E02E3D6BCF4735A19BCA1DE97281 at 131.188.40.189:443) 
09.01.2018 12:29:42.900 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
09.01.2018 12:29:42.900 [WARN]  9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
09.01.2018 12:37:41.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.01.2018 12:37:41.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.01.2018 12:37:41.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.01.2018 12:37:41.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Most Programms and Websites are restricted so I dont have much room to move around (I think I have tried everything to find out my IP-Adress)

CMD is blocked too

I´m not much of a pro with computers so please explain your solutions clearly 
the best i accomplished so far is to install an alternate Browser and to download Tor

many thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like standard censorship. You should try using bridges and pluggable transports. obfs4 and meek will be your best options.

Comment: Schools provide secure computers facilities for your protection. Instead of seeking to bypass it, have you considered challenging the protection level with the sysadmins or raising the issue with your parents?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your school is blocking all connections to tor servers (including directory servers).

To bypass this block you can try using the built-in bridges or get some from [https://bridges.torproject.org](https://bridges.torproject.org/) using another computer.

For additional information see: [Tor project: Bridges](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en)

Answer (score -1):

If your School Computer has a USB port, then you can use an live OS to it.
The best choice is Tails OS Because it has inbuilt Tor browser and is specially used for Plug-n-play type system.
It might work on school computer as they also have Suggested on their Website.
Google Tails OS, go to it's website and learn how to do it all!
Hope it helps.

Comment: presence of USB ports is not the same as BIOS/UEFI allowing boot over USB (this is a giant security pitfall)